# 5 card draw - discard 2 or 3

Tags: probability, poker

In 5 card draw you can discard up to 4.

Say you have a pair of kings and an ace.  I would like the math behind keep the ace or draw 3.

If you draw 3 you have a better chance of trips.

But two pair with a pair of aces is only 1 hand down from trips.

What are the chances of improving with discard 2 versus 3?

Drawing 3 you have more chances to hit a king (or 2).

Drawing 2 you have 5 cards to hit - 2 K and 3 A.

Comment: You can calculate the probabilities all you want, but in the end, "should" is not really an objective thing in a game like this. It all comes down to how risky you are personally willing to play, not to mention what signals you send to the other players (how will their being be affected by you discarding two versus three cards?) We cannot answer that.

Comment: Down vote may I ask what the problem is?

Comment: Wild guess as to the reason of downvote: your question is not up to our [standards for a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). I think the downvoters are right, but I also think it's terrible that they don't leave a comment explaining.

Comment: @Arthur I am asking about the math behind the decision.

Comment: Then if you want a good answer, and not too many downvotes and close votes, you ought to show a bit of your own work. And "I have no clue" isn't good enough, because [I don't believe that that's true](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @Arthur I do have clue.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intuitively, the chance of improving has to be better drawing three.  When you draw the first of three, you might get a match and have improved.  Otherwise, you are drawing two to a pair plus one card so have the same chance for improvement as if you kept an ace.

To compute the chance of improvement, it is easier to compute the chance of no improvement and subtract from $1$.  If you keep a pair plus and ace, you do not improve on the first card with probability $\frac {42}{47}$ because there are five cards of $47$ that can help you.  If you didn't improve on the first the chance you fail $\frac {38}{46}$ of the time as there are now eight cards that can help.  The chance of improvement is then $$1-\frac {42}{47}\frac {38}{46}\approx 0.2618$$

For drawing three to a pair, the same logic gives the chance of improvement as 
$$1-\frac{45}{47}\frac {41}{46}\frac {37}{45}\approx 0.2983$$

Comment: Check your denominators in the drawing three to a pair case.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig:  thanks.  Fixed

Answer (score 0):

I am going to ignore drawing a pair.

Say AKKT7

52-5 = 47 cards left

I am going to ignore drawing another pair in both cases.

Discard AT7 what is the chance of trip K or quad K.

$$\dfrac{\binom{2}{2}\cdot\binom{45}{1}+\binom{2}{1}\cdot\binom{45}{2}}{\binom{47}{3}} = 0.1248843663$$

Discard T7 what is the chance of trip K or quad K or an A.

$$\dfrac{\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{1}\cdot\binom{42}{2}}{\binom{47}{2}} = 0.2035152636$$

You are 63% more likely to improve drawing 3 but you also are more likely to draw to a weaker hand. Intuitively that number seem reasonable. How often is 2 pair going to lose to trips?  Not often but when it does you are likely to lose a big pot. So I think I would stay with draw 3.

Comment: Why ignore drawing a pair?  Your conclusion does not match your computation.  Your numbers claim the chance of improvement is higher drawing two, which is not correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan Because I am not sure how to do that yet.  It is going to be close with to same with both.  I wanted to get a feel for the difference.

Comment: @RossMillikan I did want to look at the nutted 2 pair with an ace and trips.  But I left the question as just improve.